# Why do people repeatedly hit the phone hook switch when disconnected?

Tags: columbo

Watching a "Columbo" episode recently (c.1971), it had a scene that I realized I used to see a lot in older movies and TV shows.  A woman is talking on her rotary phone, when the person on the other end is suddenly cut off.

"Hello?" she says.  Then she rapidly presses the hook switch of the phone several times, all the while saying "Hello? HELLO?"

How was pressing the hook switch repeatedly supposed to help?  Was it supposed to restore certain kinds of lost connections?

I'm old enough to remember old phone technology, but we never used the hook switch on the phone other than to hang up the phone (or press once quickly for call waiting).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of people shouting "Hello" into the phone several times after they've clearly been disconnected?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32874/whats-the-purpose-of-people-shouting-hello-into-the-phone-several-times-after)

Comment: @wbogacz This Q is focused on the hook switch, not the "hellos" of the other question.

Comment: Related: [Why do people clear the screen multiple times when using a calculator?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/); [Why do users click randomly and rapidly when an application hangs?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39413/)

Comment: I can also confirm that (cde & BowlOfRed's answer)is correct but wouldjust add that going further back in history rather flash a light the indicator was a round shape that appeared in a hole, known as a 'DollsEye'. When this dropped down it made a click sound. 'Flashing' the switch hooks repeated the sound and this could attract the operator when they were not paying attention.

Comment: I don't have any expertise to answer, but I've noticed that I often repeatedly click the home button for no good reason if my iPhone's battery suddenly out, or the mouse button if my computer crashes - I always sort of assumed this was an older example of whatever human instinct leads to this.

Comment: Very, very related question on SciFi - [How does David Lightman in WarGames manage to hack a computer by dialing a number?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66882/how-does-david-lightman-in-wargames-manage-to-hack-a-computer-by-dialing-a-numbe)

Comment: See: [Does hanging up on a UK landline call not terminate the connection?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/100268/11825) at Security SE

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I believe that by 1970 (at least in most places), this behavior did not really accomplish anything very useful, but would have been more of a habit.

However not too much earlier, operators would have been used extensively when completing calls.  Repeatedly pressing the hook would cause a light in the office to flash, directing the operator to pick up.  Since the operator might be able to assist with some types of dropped connections, the learned response to an unexpectedly dead line would be to call her in by cycling the hook.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The automated switching equipment that used pulse dialing wouldn't have reacted favorably to repeatedly pressing the hook switch - but the operators are signaled when someone did this on non-automated systems.

Comment: This seems like the best explanation as to why a movie character would hope that repeatedly pressing the hook switch as fast as possible might possibly restore her connection.  (Of course it never actually works in any movie, ever....)

Comment: This is most likely correct. When I was in the Navy, serving in the Azores in 1993, the phone system there was given/sold to them by the US, but it was a phone system from the 1930's. This meant that all phones were rotary, (or pulse if they had buttons),  as all calls I made were international, (home, to the US). the operator would place them for me manually, and they would very often get disconnected.  when that happened it would piss me off and I'd start hitting the hook switch repeatedly to get the operator's attention as quickly as possible so they could dial the other side back.

Comment: Wow, this also explains why the button on some 80s and 90s phones that would hang up and pick up again (to access certain call features.) was called "Flash".

Answer (score 31):

Actually, on rotary phones (and maybe on some early touch-tone phones), that 'hang-up' lever, if pressed quickly and lightly, would send a signal that was equivalent to the dialing the number one (or however many times you pressed it). It was actually possible to dial that way if you were careful (why would this be needed? well, say you were a child, and some silly adult had applied a lock to the rotary dial...).  I tried it once, back in the day when I first heard about it, and it DID work.

Anyway, back in those days, if one party accidentally pressed the 'hang-up' lever, and then immediately released it, the connection was not necessarily closed. Sometimes, pressing the lever again would have the effect of 'bringing the connection back,' even though it was still there. This became an issue again when call-waiting was introduced...you might think you've hung up on someone, but actually one of you is in 'on the other line' without actually talking to anybody, and 'hanging up' again, would 'restore' the connection.

Comment: [Phreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking) phones FTW.

Comment: @Johnny , that sounds reasonable.  But would the standard procedure be to stab repeatedly at the hook switch?  I can understand pressing it one time, but it seems like the TV/movie trope usually has the character clicking the hook switch 4-5 times as fast as possible (while saying "HELLO?")

Comment: When I was a child I realised that if you stab at the hook switch you could "lose" the call and then reconnect it with a further stab. When the call was lost the line would fall silent. There was noise on the line, so it wasn't dead, but neither party could communicate. A stab of the right duration, hence repeated stabbing, would bring it back. This was in the UK in the 90s.

Comment: Could it be a way to "buzz" the switchingboard operator instead? I.e. she would come online and you could ask her to kindly put the plugs back in or somesuch :-)

Comment: This is one of the reasons that the emergency number was often 999 or 911 when countries were picking which three-digit number (as most numbers where within an area) to use; 111 was more likely to be dialled by mistake (wind hitting the phone lines could also do it). In New Zealand they had the opposite click-number arrangement, so a single click would dial a 9, and they chose 111 as their emergency number.

Comment: `why would this be needed?` - Technically, it wasn't needed, it's just how dialing worked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strowger_switch. When people (like yourself) began discovering how to hack the system it was replaced by CCITT protocols (first ss5 which got hacked using the famous cap'n crunch whistle then ss7 in use up to now which will probably be replaced by VOIP). The system was brilliantly simple - the pulses trigger relays to rotate and pauses cause the next relay to be selected.

Comment: Also, if you could whistle at just the right frequency, you could disconnect a call.  No BS.  Did that one to my parents a few times before they figured out what I was doing.  :oD

Comment: This would never have "brought back" a dead connection when on an automated switching network using pulse dialing.  It's true that briefly pressing the hook switch didn't always disconnect the call (you had to press it for a minimum period of time to terminate the call), but it never was able to reconnect a disconnected switched session. This behavior is simply a hold-over from when switching was managed by operators - repeatedly pressing the hook switch got the operator's attention.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning as an aside, this dialing technique is actually used by Hannibal Lecter in the movie Red Dragon.

Answer (score 9):

Phones can dial in three ways. Normal phones use Dual Tone Multiple Frequency (DTMF) dialing, where each number is a unique pair of two frequencies in a column x row manner. Cell phones use digital connections, but still use DTMF when the call is active so you can access an IVR.

Older phones use Pulse Dialing. Each number dialed actually breaks and makes the phone line connection n number of times. Real Rotary phones use this exclusively. Most normal phones have a switch that allow you to switch between DTMF and Pulse. This is still supported even in 2015. In the movie **Hackers**, one of the characters uses this to make an unauthorized call while in jail, by pressing the hook ten times really fast, to "dial" 0, to get the operator.

This break and make connection is also used to switch between lines, as in call waiting or placing a line on hold, or to set up a 3-way call. Some phones have a dedicated button for it called Flash.

**The reason that people used to repeatedly press the hook is a combination of the above. Sometimes you are placed on hold or on the other line or to get the other side's attention.**

Mainly this was before some modern phone signals were used, such as Calling Party Control. We all know this as the disconnect tone, and the off the hook tone. If you watch some shows, people used to take the phone off the hook to block calls from ringing. That behavior stopped when CPC introduced the off the hook tone, which is very loud and annoying. **And more relevant to the question, the disconnect tone which tells one side that the other side has disconnected.** Prior to CPC, you had no way of telling if the silence on the phone was silence or that the call was lost. The disconnect tone fixed that. **People no longer had to toggle the hook to know you were hung up on, the BEEEEEP did it for you.**

Oh the ever evolving PSTN technology.

Comment: The "flash" wasn't introduced until much later, and only involved automated switching equipment.  The only time when pressing the hook switch accomplished anything at the middle or end of a call was when the switching equipment wasn't automated - when operators ruled the lines.  They *were* signaled when the hook switch was repeatedly pressed.  So this isn't a "combination of the above" it is merely a hold-over from the time when switching wasn't automated.

Comment: Because it is so hard to distinguish between no connection/faulty equipment etc. and no one talking, most modern telephone systems (especially IP based digital ones) use [comfort noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_noise).

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that (cde & BowlOfRed's answer) - the other answers aren't quite right because the technology started changing so rapidly in the 60's and 70's after the transistor was invented and finally found its way to the phone system.  Everyone was used to hitting the phone hook repeatedly to hang up - it took a while for this old habit to die out.

I was born in the 50's and actually used those phones back in the day.  Hanging up back then frequently didn't break the connection because everything was done by switchboard operators.  I always thought it was weird that I could hang up and then pick up the phone 5 minutes later and still be connected to the other phone.  Hitting the phone hook rapidly flashed a light on the switchboard operator's panel, which attracted her attention.  She would manually pull the cord out of the panel, and the call would finally be disconnected.

Comment: So if you're trying to re-establish a connection, why would you signal the operator to disconnect the call?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I wasn't trying to re-establish the connection when I picked up the handset.  I was testing to see if the call was still connected.

Comment: "Hitting the phone hook rapidly flashed a light on the switchboard operator's panel, which attracted her attention. She would manually pull the cord out of the panel, and the call would finally be disconnected."  The question is about rapidly hitting the handswitch, which you state in your answer is a signal to disconnect the call.

Comment: Back then, we thought of hitting the hook repeatedly as a sort of reset button - we did it when things were wrong with the phone or to make sure the call got disconnected.  To hang up, we usually just put the receiver on the phone base and walked away.  It didn't matter if the call was still connected, because eventually the switchboard operator would see the light on her panel for that cord had been on too long and she would listen in briefly for dead air.  If no one was talking, she'd pull the cord.If we wanted to hang up and call someone else right away

Comment: Sorry, I got timed out while editing.  Here's what I was trying to say:  Ah, I see the confusion.  Back then, we thought of hitting the hook repeatedly as a sort of speedy reset button that could be used in a variety of situations -- before a call to make sure we had a dial tone, at the end of a call to make sure the line was disconnected, and at the end of a conversation when we wanted to disconnect without putting the handset down to hang up and to start dialing a new number.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill, but it sounds like what you're suggesting would do the opposite of what the movie character wanted.  The person rapidly stabbing at the hook switch in movies is usually desperately trying to be reconnected, not disconnected.

Comment: In a panic situation, hitting the hook sometimes worked to restore a disconnected line.  My mother used to be a switchboard operator and I watched her work. She would "pull the plug" to disconnect a call, but because the numerous criss-cross cables on the panel were confusing, she would pause before releasing the cable with her hand, in case she pulled the wrong cable.  If the customer flashed the light, she would reconnect the call.

Comment: @Bill - That sounds like a better answer than the one you have posted, actually.

Comment: @Bobson - Yeah, it took me a few re-readings of the original question to realize that it was about a woman trying to get reconnected.  

An even better question is "_Why did the phone suddenly get cut off in the middle of a conversation in the first place?_"  My answer got a little buried (above): "eventually the switchboard operator would see the light on her panel for that cord had been on too long and she would listen in briefly for dead air. If no one was talking, she'd pull the cord."

Comment: Also, the original question referred to 1971 (season 1 of Columbo.)  The pilots were created from 1968, at a time when the phone company was transitioning from huge banks of switchboard operators to somewhat crude automated systems.  It took them a long time to do this (we used to get notices in our phone book every year explaining this), it was done unevenly geographically, and sometimes it would fail and they would go back to operators.  No one knew what caused a disconnect, so we just resorted to the old habit of banging on the phone hook in the hope that it would magically reconnect.